# retry-max value in oozie 4.2.0 version

Tags: oozie, oozie-workflow

I have oozie 4.2.0 HDP version, i want to use 'Max-retries' for my spark-action as well as shell action.
When i submit the workflow after ERROR state it goes to USER-RETRY state, and then again retries it.
When i look into oozie -info for that action it gives me number of retries as '0'.

I looked for '-retries' but its available in 5.x.xversion.

```
<workflow-app xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.3" name="wf-name">
<action name="a" retry-max="2" retry-interval="1">
</action>
```

Is there any way by which i can look the nunber of retries attempts ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you'll get to know if you open oozie job logs. Once you open the OOzie URL, click on the oozie job, then select the action, it gives the link to resource manager page, if you go through the logs, it will be specified there. If it doesn't succeed, it says sleep for a interval and retry 2, ...,etc. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks fir the response, i will check that.
Will that creates a new yarn application , like if i have retry-max set to '2' will get two yarn application , in case of action is killed ?

Comment: No Mohit, it doesn't create two yarn applications, it creates only one yarn application. It retries for max number of specified times, even then if it doesn't get catch hold of the specific data region/table/etc it gets killed.

Comment: Two things here :
- I can not see any retries on resource manager side, it only holds the log for last application created.
- WHen i did watch command on oozie jobId , i can see that multilple, in our case two, yarn applications got created.

Please  share our inputs on this.

Comment: Are you sure that those are two yarn applications, and not attempt IDs?

Comment: Once you open the job logs, you should see something like this: Showing 4096 bytes of 54808 total. Click here for the full log. You should click on here to open full logs, there you can find each retry details.

Comment: yes for that action it keeps on changing the Job_id (job_123456789),So for 2 reties iI can see three job_ids getting updated while watching the oozie job

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186122/discussion-between-mohit-rane-and-bigdatageek).